# django alternative to prevent header poison

Tags: python, django, security, content-security-policy

Firstly I don't speak English very well, but anyway...

i know I need to use allowed_hosts, but I need to use all "*" and a header attack can cause something like:

```
<script src = "mysite.com/js/script.js"> <script>
```

to

```
<script src = "attacker.com/js/script.js"> <script>
```

or

mysite.com/new_password=blabla&token=blabla8b10918gd91d1b0i1

to

attacker.com/new_password=blabla&token=blabla8b10918gd91d1b0i1

But all static files are  load on a nodejs server "cdn.mysite.com" and all domains are in the database, so I always take the domain from the database to compare with the request header, and use the domain from the database of data to send anything to the client:

views.py:

```
def Index(request):

    url = request.META['HTTP_HOST']

    cf = Config.objects.first()

    if cf.domain == url:

        form = regForm()

        return render(request, 'page/site/home.html', {'form': form})

    elif cf.user_domain == url:

        ur = request.user.is_authenticated

        if ur:
    
            config = {'data' : request.user}

            lojas  = 'json.loads(request.user.user_themes)'

            return render(request, 'app/home.html', {"config":config, "lojas":lojas})

        else:

            forml = loginForm()

            return render(request, 'page/users/login/login.html', {'form':forml})

    else:
        redirect("//" + cf.domain)
```

Would that still be unsafe to use this way?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create yet one bike shed. The `allowed_hosts` settings is totally enough to prevent spoofing the host name in the request (you can see in [Practical HTTP Host header attacks](https://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html) how the spoofing of host name works).

`allowed_hosts` means domains kind of [YourSite.com, www.YourSite.com, *.YourSite.com] - this is domain names on which you site should operate (not from which you site can load external scripts).

And use HTTP/2 instead of HTTP/1.1 on server, because:

> according to the HTTP / 1.1 protocol specification, when specifying an
> absolute path of a resource, the Host header value is **ignored**, and the
> **host from the resource path** is taken as it. This leads to the fact
> that even a securely configured web server in this case accepts a
> request with a spoofed Host value, and the web application that uses
> **HOST instead of SERVER_NAME** is vulnerable to this attack.

So if you do use SERVER_NAME - this kind of attacks is not affects you.

If you wish to control the possible spoofing of scripts on public CDNs - use the:

- [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) HTTP header (you could select you language to read).
- [SubResource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) (currently is <s>not supported by Safari</s> supported in Safari 12)

Comment: But in my case the change of the domain is dynamic, at any time there must be a new domain added by the user, so it has to be something automatic, that can support thousands of domains

Comment: If thousands domains - it's better to manage those via database, so you way is Ok. Just verify that HOST/SERVER_NAME (the `Host:` field from HTTP header) presents in database, and you will avoid this kinds of spoofing.